# Insert shapes in my userform

Tags: excel, vba

I saw an example on the internet of a UserForm with a circle shape. I tried to do by myself but I had a problem to insert the shape in my userform.

The goal is: the red circle will move 5 cm to right every 100 seconds. But I don´t have any clue about how to insert it. I searched on internet and found very complicated ways. As I am newbie on VBA, it´s difficult to understand the other methods as http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/514521-drawing-shapes-userform.html.

Could sb help me, please? I just want to know how to insert the shape. The code I can do...

[image]

Thanks, guys!

Comment: Are you asking how to add this using code? Or how to add it to a UserForm at all? Use the "Image" control from the toolbox, then insert the picture. Format it to be "not visible" if you don't want it until a certain point. Then make it visible and change the co-ordinates... Please note that Stack Overflow is not a free code-writing or tutorial service (see the guidelines in the [help] on asking questions). You need to have done a certain amount of research, post the results (code) with a specific question about HOW it's not working. My tip should get you started...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image you have shown is of VB not VBA. In VBA you can not insert a shape, just an image of a shape.

To insert an image you will find the option in the tool box where you got the buttons from.

Comment: Ahn, I got it. I already know how to insert images. My apologies!

Answer (score 0):

This is how to load the picture to the userform image control.

```
userform.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture("Image_path")
```